# RubyGems Update Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

So I ran `sudo gem update` in my terminal and I got this (Please notice the error at the bottom of the picture):

[image]

Now whenever I run anything related to gem such as `sudo gem install cocoapods` or `sudo gem update --system` I keep getting this error:

[image]

Can someone help me figure out what the problem is here. I tried to find solutions online but got no luck...

Comment: `bundle update` or `bundle install` this are working properly? Do you using any ruby version manager? if you using ruby version manager like rvm, you can do a  `rvm implode` to reinstall rvm.

Comment: It said command not found for `bundle update`? And also no I am not using any RVM.

Comment: `[sudo] gem install bundler` `bundle install` run this first. If it works and also use ruby version manager like `rvm`. It will be good for you. https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: The thing is when I try to use gem like `[sudo] gem install bundler bundle install` I get an error like the second image shown above. So I can't even use gem in the terminal. Which is what I am trying to fix.

Comment: I am trying to install cocoapods using `sudo gem install cocoapods` but whenever I use the gem command it gives the error as shown in the second image in my post.

Comment: First install rvm. Then install
`gem install rails`    
`[sudo] gem install bundler`
`bundle install`
`gem install railties`

Comment: But I am not able to use gem at all in the terminal. Every time I use gem it keeps giving me that error as shown in the second image in my post. I installed RVM also and tried to run the command you told me to but whenever I use gem I get that error.

Comment: Yes because you environment is broken. You need to reinstall from begining.

Comment: Oh ok. So I installed RVM using this command: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`. Can you please tell me what to do next? I got this command from their website: https://rvm.io

Comment: Great. follow this guideline. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-rvm. If you using mac follow this guide. http://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/

Comment: In the mac guide they say to install the mpapis public key so do I run this command in terminal: `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net
    --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`?

Comment: yeah, It is for certificaiton.